# How detect running application and send event to this application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How detect running application in android phone?
How send event to running application (click on button) ?

For example: if there is a running Play Google app, then send an event, click on the search input

Comment: You can't, at least not without root.  This is for security reasons-  they don't want apps to be able to mess with other apps.

Comment: I think its called clickjacking. It is a security issue.

Comment: I have a root. Program running on foreground

Comment: Do you know what Broadcast Receivers the other application has implemented? If you know which events it can handle it's easy to send out some kind of broadcast.